# React : Search bar capturing key but not showing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a complete beginner. I have the following React component where I need to display a table with data and perform a search on it using a generated API using Laravel as backend.

Displaying data works great, searching data **directly from the API link works**, but when trying to perform the search on the table, all the data that was showing disappears and no result is displaying.

If it can help, in chrome's console when typing I have the following

```
SyntheticEvent {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, nativeEvent: InputEvent, type: "change", target: input.form-control, …}

SyntheticEvent {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchInstances: FiberNode, nativeEvent: InputEvent, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, …}
```

I believe I have a problem in `handleSearchChange`

```
class Patient extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)          
        
        this.state = {
            patients : [],
        };

        this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
    }

       // Problem in this one
        handleSearchChange(key){   
        console.log(key);
        fetch("api/patients/search?q="+key)
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({
            patients:[]
          }); 
        })
      } 
      
        componentDidMount() {
            axios.get('api/patients')
            .then(response => {
              this.setState({
                patients: response.data})
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));                
        }

        render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Container>
              <div>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Search..."
                    onChange= onChange={this.handleSearchChange}
                  /> 
              </div>
    
              <Table>
                <Thead>
                  <Tr>
                    <Th>ID</Th>
                    <Th>FIRST NAME</Th>
                    <Th>LAST NAME</Th>
                  </Tr>
                </Thead>
    
                <Tbody>
    
                  {this.state.patients.reverse().map((patient) => (
                    <Tr>
                      <Td>
                        {patient.id}
                      </Td>
                      <Td>
                        {patient.firstname}
                      </Td>
                      <Td>
                        {patient.lastname}
                      </Td>
                    </Tr>
                  ))}
    
                </Tbody>
    
              </Table>
            </Container>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default Patient;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the problem with your input

```
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Search..."
                    onChange= onChange={this.handleSearchChange}
                  />
```

You need to capture onChange event from input, get the value then send it to handleSearchChange function, like this:

```
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Search..."
                    onChange={e => this.handleSearchChange(e.target.value)}
                  />
```

You might question why `e.target.value`, it's the event object, you can console.log it to see more detail.

Edit: in handleSearchChange function, you also need to setState the patients gotten from response,just like what you did in componentDidMount method

Comment: Thanks. I did what you suggested, now I have the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: That's because `this.state.patients` is undefined, you should check your api response.

It's also best practice to make sure this.state.patients is an array before mapping, usually this is what I do `Array.isArray(this.state.patients) && this.state.patients.map...`

Comment: Yes it's working. If you don't mind asking, how did you come up with `e.target.value`

Comment: Instead of `e => this.handleSearchChange(e.target.value)`, you can `e => console.log(e)` to see what propertíe and methods does the event object has